# How to open a dialog programmatically inside an Icon Menu using React Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I have an icon menu and I have an array which holds the possible values when I open the icon menu. For example,

```
listItems = {
    [
        {
            label: 'ZERO',
            type: 'positive',
            value: 0,
        },
        {
            label: 'ONE',
            type: 'danger',
            value: '1',
        },
        {
            label: 'TWO',
            type: 'warning',
            value: '2',
        },
        {
            label: 'THREE',
            type: 'default',
            value: '3',
        }
    ]
}
```

When I set the initial value as 1, the label ONE is shown in the menu.
Based on the value selected, I want to show a dialog(http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog). So when the user selects ONE from the menu, I want the dialog to be open. Inside my dialog few input text fields will capture some input upon pressing the OK button on the dialog.
Generally, the dialog is triggered under the onClick or onChange methods of a typical Button. In my case I want to trigger the dialogs under the selected menu option.
My code is as follows:

```
onItemSelection = {(value) => {
    if (value === 1) {
      console.log(`${value} is clicked`);
      //Trigger the Dialog here
      <Dialog
          title="Dialog With Actions"
          actions={actions}
          modal={false}
          open={this.handleOpen}
      >
      </Dialog>
```

My handleOpen method is as follows,

```
handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
};
```

However as of now, when the option is selected only the console statement is being printed but the dialog is not opening. How to solve this issue?

Comment: `listItems` isn't a valid object

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are incorrect here

First: In the function `onItemSelection` you have a `Dialog` which is incorrect since you need to render the Dialog

Second: The `open` prop of `Dialog` requires a `bool` value and what you are supplying to it is a function `this.handleOpen`

You can correctly write it as

```
handleOpen = () => {
   this.setState({open: true});
};

onItemSelection={(value) => {
        if (value === 1) {
           console.log(`${value} is clicked`);
           //Trigger the Dialog here
           this.handleOpen();
        }
}

render() {
    return (
        <Dialog
            title="Dialog With Actions"
            actions={actions}
            modal={false}
            open={this.state.open}
          >
          </Dialog>
    )
}
```

and obviously you also need a way to close the Dialog which can be done by setting the `state` variable `open` as false.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested, yet the same problem persists. The log is printed, but the dialog never opens. I changed couple of things as you have mentioned. But I have no clue why the dialog isn't getting triggered.

Comment: Nope, No errors. All I see is the console statement which is getting printed. I dont see any warnings or errors in the console.

Comment: I will have to see more code to be able to help further. Can you create a codeSandbox